# Number vs. no. vs. # in scientific papers?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, numbers, ordinal-numbers, scientific-language

This is kinda an extension to: [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/469413/when-is-it-ok-to-use-symbol-vs-the-word-number-in-writing).

I am writing a scientific paper and have a numbered list. Now, when I want to refer to that list I want to say something like: *"This issue is closely related to item number 12."*

As a non-native I'm not sure whether that sounds 'normal' or if it would be easier to read with "no. 12" or "#12" or option number(?) three, just "item 12".

Comment: It would depend on the text you use to label or introduce your list—are they items, facts, issues?

Comment: There is no single correct answer; this is largely a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style. identify a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Comment: If you intend your readership to include English speakers from outside the US it would be better to avoid the use of the hash sign '#'. It's not usually used to mean 'number' the UK and, I suspect, in other regions as well. Given the wide use of it in social media in the form of hashtags it would probably confuse. #avoidliketheplague

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Item 2", not "Item number 2" (and not No. or № or #).  Similarly use "Figure 4" not "Figure number 4", and "Paragraph 3" not "Paragraph number 3".

Comment: And how can anyone judge whether this answer is correct? If you are new to this list you should consult the help on answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a list of equations or scientific propositions, one convention is to number the list as in the following example:

X + Y = 8     (1)

X = Y         (2)

Z = X.Y       (3)

We find Y by solving (1) and (2). Z may be calculated from (3).